# Excel-VBA : Create function that accepts mathematical equation

Tags: vba, excel

This is my problem: I want to create a function that takes X and puts it in a equation in my function.

I think that the script will always be like this :

```
 Function Myfunction(x As Integer)
   Myfunction = <EQUATION like 2*x>
 End Function
```

What I need to do is to put the equation in cells as a text and Myfunction will take it. So, the equation is changing all the time.

Comment: `Myfunction = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("2 * " & x )`

Comment: Psst @ScottCraner - `Evaluate` not `Evalutate` ;)

Comment: @Rory Yeah yeah yeah.  What do you expect from a dumb construction worker?  Weez cant spellz wort beans.  I edited the original comment.  Thanks.

Comment: Here is an exemple of the equation i'm using   y = -32417x6 + 95075x5 - 109325x4 + 61800x3 - 17705x2 + 2647,8x + 157,73    and its just an exemple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `Evaluate` function - see this code example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Debug.Print EvalForX("(2+X)*44", 14)
    Debug.Print EvalForX("X^3", 22)
    Debug.Print EvalForX("(X+10)*(X-3)", 7)
    Debug.Print EvalForX("X", 12)
End Sub

Function EvalForX(ByVal strEquation As String, ByVal intX As Integer) As Double
    EvalForX = Evaluate(Replace(strEquation, "X", CStr(intX), 1, -1, vbTextCompare))
End Function
```

This will output:

```
 704 
 10648 
 68 
 12
```

And can be used in the worksheet as a User Defined Function:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the final solution

EvalForX = Evaluate(Replace(Replace(strEquation, "X", CStr(intX), 1, -1, vbTextCompare), ",", ".", 1, -1, vbTextCompare))